# what is the difference nn.Embedding and nn.Linear

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, word2vec

what I learned about embedding layer is that it is trained in advance using many document with the hypothesis "Similar words appear around similar word."

And there is many way to train the layer CBOW,Skip Gram, GloVe etc..

But in Pytorch, the embedding layer is just nn.Embedding and there is no parameter to set window size.

I don't know how it is trained and as far as I've found there is no post to let me know how it is trained.

If it is trained just to reduce the loss of final output, it doesn't differ with nn.Linear

So what I want to know is that how nn.Embedding is trained(with CBOW, Skip Gram?)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're attempting to understand the concept of "embeddings" narrowly from the perspective of NLP tasks, but they're a general concept. An embedding is a tensor that represents something (possibly a word or character, but could be something else too).

If you want to train a model on text, you'd need some way to represent tokens of that text. One option would be for each character to be represented by a 26-dim tensor where one value is set to `1` and the rest `0` (e.g. `'a' == [1, 0, 0, .... 0]`, `'z' == [0, 0, ....0, 1]`). This might be tedious.

Alternatively you could "learn" some smaller floating point tensor to represent each character. If you wanted this embedding to have size 5, with 26 possible characters you could do this with:

```
emb = nn.Embedding(26, 5)
```

If you wanted to feed the letter 'a' into your model, the representation (with length 5) of the letter 'a', generated in the first layer of your model, would be:

```
emb(torch.tensor(0))
```

A word 'az' would be represented as:

```
emb(torch.tensor([0, 25]))
```

Initially these embeddings would be pretty random, but as you train your model, depending on your task, it would learn to represent characters in meaningful ways. E.g. vowels might be closer to each other in embedding space produced by your embedding layer.

This same mechanism can be used to generate embeddings to represent periods of time, positions, words, etc. Essentially anything for which there is some fixed number of embeddings to generate.

Comment: then, you mean that when embedding layer try to reduce the loss of output about label, similar word is located to similar word in vector space?